# Java program gives me FileNotFoundException when the file I am reading from exists but then works perfectly fine if I handle the exception

Tags: java, file-io, filenotfoundexception

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class WordJumble {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        File file = new File("F:/Files/Topic.txt");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(file); 

        String title = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println(title);
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
            System.out.println(sc.nextLine());
        }
    }
}
```

Currently the program does what I want it to, but why is it giving me an error about the file not existing? When I add the `throws` clause to ignore the error it is able to find the file without issue.

Comment: Add `System.out.println(file.exists());` to test if Java can see the file, otherwise it's not accessible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the wording of the error may be a little confusing, the error isn't a FileNotFoundException in and of itself but is instead a complaint that you aren't dealing with the *possibility* of such an exception being thrown. All your compiler is telling you is that you need to deal with the possibility of the file not being where you think it is. Therefore, when you add `throws FileNotFoundException` to the method signature the compiler is satisfied and your error goes away.

Answer (score 0):

When you said 'add the statement to ignore the error' you meant adding the 'throws...' clause to the definition of `main` so it would compile cleanly.  Right?

What's going on is that `Scanner` many throw a `FileNotFoundException` if the file is not found.  This exception must be handled (caught) somewhere.

Instead, you elected not to handle, and said that it could propagate out from `main`.

The appropriate way to do this is use a `try - catch` construction.

```
try {
   Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
   :
   :
catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
   ... print an error or something ...
}
```

This sort of approach is used so that the error handling is 'out of line' of the main flow of the code.